# Retrieving the last level of categories in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a category table in MySql database that holds the following data.

```
id  name                      parent
-------------------------------------
1   Web development           0
2   Application development   0
3   Linux                     0
4   Misc                      0
5   Php                       1
6   Mysql                     1
7   Javascript                1
8   CSS                       1
9   C plus plus               2
10  wxWidgets                 2
11  Tutorials                 3
12  My thoughts               4
13  Java                      1
14  JSP                       13
15  Spring                    14
16  Spring 3.0                15
17  Spring 3.1                15
18  JSF                       13
19  Oracle                    0
20  Oracle 8i                 19
21  Oracle 91                 19
22  JSF 2.0                   18
23  JSF 2.2                   18
```

I need the following output.

```
5   Php                       1
9   C plus plus               2
11  Tutorials                 3
12  My thoughts               4
6   Mysql                     1
7   Javascript                1
8   CSS                       1
10  wxWidgets                 2
22  JSF 2.0                   18
23  JSF 2.2                   18
16  Spring 3.0                15
17  Spring 3.1                15
20  Oracle 8i                 19
21  Oracle 91                 19
```

The result set should contain only the last level of each category. This can be done using a function in MySql. but is there a way to achieve this using an SQL query only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check it .. It will work

```
SELECT id, name, parent
FROM category 
WHERE id NOT 
IN ( SELECT parent FROM category )
```

Comment: do u wnt as same order as u print in output ?

Comment: What I found difficult looked very simple from your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hows about this?  It will query `category` and get the `id` of the rows that have a `parent` of 0 and then find each row that references that parent record.

```
select * from category as t1 where t1.parent in (select t2.id from category as t2 where t2.parent=0)
```

Comment: The result set doesn't contain the row with the ids `16` and `17` with the query you posted. The table maintains infinite level of categories. Thanks anyway!

Comment: How do you know to get those records? Based on parsing the name? Those parent records don't have a parent ID of 0.

Comment: They have `4` levels i.e. web development->Java->JSP->Spring and finally the `Spring` contains the last level as `Spring 3.0` and `Spring 3.1`. The result set should contain only these last level of each categories i.e. `Spring 3.0` and `Spring 3.1`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    dr.ID,
    dr.name,
    dr.Parent
FROM category as c
inner JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as ID, name , Parent FROM category WHERE parent != '0' GROUP BY parent) as dr ON dr.id = c.id
group by c.id
order by dr.Parent
```